# evaluation of an expression recursively using array and stack

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, stack

```
exp = a | b | c | d
brackets = set('[(()())]')

def evaluate():
        for i in brackets[:]:
            arr[i] = ('''1st 2 exp''')
            print(arr)
            i = i + 1
```

an expression is given `a|b|c|d|e`. Then there is an array where we have to store the 1st 2 values in `a[0]` and then the `(a[0]|c)` is stored in `a[1]`.
How can we attain this?

Comment: What is `brackets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

```
brackets="a|b|c|d|e"
```

you could do

```
[brackets[0:x] for x in range(3, len(brackets), 2)]
```

which gives

```
['a|b', 'a|b|c', 'a|b|c|d']
```